# Extracting every nth character from delimited array using regex

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a column that contains multiple industry codes per record, separated by comma, and each with various lengths (from 2 to 6 digits). A record in my data frame looks something like:

```
naics <- c("5413, 541410, 11, 23611, 23, 611")
```

I want to be able to create a new array based on the number of characters in each unit. For example, here I'm extracting only four-digit numeric characters:

```
naics.four.digit <- unlist(str_extract_all(naics, "[0-9]{4}+"))
naics.four.digit
[1]"5413" "5414" "5414" "5416" "6117"
```

As you can see above I used `str_extract_all`, and the method works well. However, this method breaks down once I try to extract 3 digit and 2 digit characters.

```
naics.three.digit <- unlist(str_extract_all(naics, "[0-9]{3}+"))
naics.three.digit
[1]"541" "541" "410" "236" "611"
```

The actual desired output here would be:

```
"541" "541" "236" "611"
```

Similarly, for the two-digit output, it should be:

```
"54" "54" "11" "23" "23" "61"
```

I assume the `str_extract_all` method breaks down here because each substring comes in varying lengths. Is there a workaround for this? Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Anchor it `\b\d{3}\b` or split on `,` and trim, then `^\d{3}$` or length == 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use word boundary `\\b` followed by 3 digits (`\\d{3}`) as pattern in `str_extract_all` and it will skip the numbers having less than 3 digits

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(naics, "\\b\\d{3}")[[1]]
#[1] "541" "541" "236" "611"
```